# PrestaShop invalid UTF-8 string at offset 5 on 1.7.4.3

Tags: prestashop

I have crazy error when put prestashop form one to another server:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 5 in /presta/classes/Dispatcher.php on line 931
```

and full

[image]

I have no idea what will be wrong:( data base have same coding, module/themes I may delete folder, error still will be here

Comment: What's wrong is probably mysql server has variable `init_connect` set to wrong value i.e. `SET NAMES latin2`. In most cases it should be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Have you modified this file in some editor? Like notepad? Without saving it with proper encoding?

Or maybe there were some issues with file transfer? Remember that it's always recommended to transfer many files as one .zip package and unpack it after upload.

At the end, this could be a server issue but my guess is that something went wrong during file transfer process.

Comment: I find solution here  http://centrumps.pl/prestashop-1-7-warning-php-startup-compilation-failed/ all work fine :)